# How to transform dictionary in python

Tags: python

How can modify the object A to look like Object B:

Obeject A:

```
{
  'first_name': {'
     'required': false,
     'enabled': false
  '},
  'last_name': {'
     'required': false,
     'enabled': false
  '}
}
```

Object(I want it look like this):

```
[
  {
   'name': first_name,
   'required': true,
   'enamble':false
  },
{
   'name': last_name,
   'required': true,
   'enamble':false
  }
]
```

Comment: This isn't valid Python; you have extra `'` marks in some places and are missing them in others.

Comment: And `true` and `false` should be `True` and `False`

Comment: Unless they should be `'true'` and `'false'`...

Comment: When posting a question to SO, you should show the work you've put into solving your problem, so that we can help at the specific spot you've gone wrong.  A great place to start, rather than SO, would be to go read about python's "list comprehensions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# Python >= 3.5
d = [{**{'name': k}, **v} for k, v in d.items()]

# Python >= 3.9
d = [{'name': k} | v for k, v in d.items()]
print(d)

# Output
[{'name': 'first_name', 'required': False, 'enabled': False},
 {'name': 'last_name', 'required': False, 'enabled': False}]
```

Input data:

```
>>> d
{'first_name': {'required': False, 'enabled': False},
 'last_name': {'required': False, 'enabled': False}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple thing to do is to use a for loop to iterate through the dictionary. When you do `for variable in dict_A`, what happens is that the variable iterates through all the keys in dict_A. So then you could use code that looks like

```
for key in dict_A:
    # the piece of code to change to dict_B, 
    # where you use dict_A[key] to access the value for each 
    # key stored in dict_A
```

Edit - And as a lot of comments have correctly pointed out, the dict_A in the question does not look like valid Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

## Code

```py
import json
b = {
  'first_name': {
     'required': "false",
     'enabled': "false"
  },
  'last_name': {
     'required': "false",
     'enabled': "false"
  }
}

output = []
for i in b:
  op = {}
  z = [d for d in b[i]]
  d = zip(z,[b[i][g] for g in z])
  op["name"] = i
  for x in d:
    op[x[0]] = x[1]
    
  output.append(op)

x = json.dumps(output, indent = 2) 
print(x)
```

## Output

```json
[
  {
    "required": "false", 
    "enabled": "false", 
    "name": "first_name"
  }, 
  {
    "required": "false", 
    "enabled": "false", 
    "name": "last_name"
  }
]
```